# How to Get "Members" of the "Territory"

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Am getting Territory Name and Id from othersource,
 i want to retreive members of the Territory in my javascript using that Territory name or Id,
 how to get that ,

```
 var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();   
 //The XRM OData end-point    
 var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";   
 var odataSetName = "TerritorySet";    
 var odataSelect = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + "(guid'" + territoryId+ "')";  

 //alert(odataSelect);  
 $.ajax({        
             type: "GET",contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   datatype: "json", url: odataSelect,beforeSend:          
             function (XMLHttpRequest) 
             {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
              },       
              success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest)
              {    
                var result_contact= data.d;                      
                var des = result_contact.Description; 
                alert(des);
                                                                   }

                },        
               error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
              {
                // alert('OData Select Failed: ' + odataSelect); 
                }  
            });
```

any help would be appreciated..
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the rest service for this kind of query.  You aren't giving much info to go off of, but I'd recommend that you download the CRM 2011 OData query Designer and build your query in the tool first.

http://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/

Then you will want to make an ajax request to retrieve the information you need.  There is an article here that shows how to do it with jquery.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx

And here without

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx

Comment: Hi, am able to retreive the ID of the region Record. now i have to retreive the members of the region

Comment: It is the same process.  Design an oData request, then process it using javascript.  Post the code you've tried if it isn't working and I'll help you fix it.